# Upgrades available but after clicking install nothing happens

Tags: 18.04, updates, terminology

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and this red triangle sign (top right on the image) appears often, and when I click there and then click `Install all updates` nothing happens. This occurs often and is a burden.

[image]

What exactly does it mean that red triangle and when does it appear? That there are updates, or upgrades?

shall I do?

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Comment: Yes, you can always run `sudo apt-get update ` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` anytime.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `ls -la /var/lib/apt/periodic`

Comment: @Terrance but that sign refers to updates, upgrades or both?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira I think upgrades and it is one that are getting stuck maybe because they need to have `sudo apt dist-upgrade` performed on them.  That happens when you see apps that are getting held back.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand the problem, because it's merely a problem of **terminology**.

What ubuntu in the top right corner GUI defines as "install updates" it's not solved by the command `sudo apt update` because this command merely downloads the latest version of available packages, but it's solved by `sudo apt upgrade`, which indeed install new versions of the packages already installed.